# Can we have merge feature for documentation?

Tags: feature-request, documentation, documentation-topics

Is there a "flagging option" for merging duplicate topics in the same category?
I noticed there are two "[Apex Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/66699)" topics in the Salesforce category.

I created one of them. I agree that one of them needs to be deleted, but what happens to the content underneath the topic? 
How can I request two topics to be merged?